# Screen incoming SMS in Symbian

Tags: sms, symbian

I'm using sockets to [read all incoming SMS](http://symbiantricks.info/tricks/silent_receiving_of_sms_messages/):

```
 `smsAddr.SetTextMatch(KNullDesC8);`
```

The ones that belong to me I accept:

```
iReadSocket.Ioctl(KIoctlReadMessageSucceeded, iStatus, NULL, KSolSmsProv);
```

The ones that are malicious (like current Silence SMS threat) I would stop
and the others I would like to pass into Inbox.

Currently my problem is in forwarding SMS into Inbox - they will appear there only after rebooting device.

Is there any API or solution to force Symbian to retry writing SMS into Inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert messages manually - take a look at [this example](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Create_Local_SMS) in the Forum Nokia Wiki. Note, however, that the example does not set character set and encoding - you may have to deal with character set conversion and encoding, which will be particularly complicated for binary messages.

How are you currently forwarding messages to the Inbox?

Comment: Currently I'm not - that's the problem. Or actually I'm creating some of my own messages (notices to user), but they are just ordinary SMS. I'm more afraid about MMS, Email, binary settings.

Comment: Seems that this is the only solution. Looks like binary messages (like phone settings) are coming in through different port, so they are not caught at all.